# Nominatim North America update

Tags: openstreetmap, update, osmosis, nominatim

I want to keep updated my fresh install of Nominatim 3.1.0. I have installed North America maps from this (http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america-latest.osm.pbf) file.

According to the article (http://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Import-and-Update/) I can use 'CONST_Replication_Url' in settings/local.php for daily country diffs update but I can't find one update file like in the article's example ('https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/ireland-and-northern-ireland-updates'). For North America I go to (http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/) and see us-midwest-updates, us-northeast-updates, us-pacific-updates, us-south-updates and us-west-updates folders...

Anybody knows where I can get one update file?

Because now I use this command ./utils/update.php --import-osmosis-all and the update process works all time...like a live update and I don't know actually this update works for only installed maps or for the whole world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update folder for North America is a step higher at 
http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america-updates/

You can find this link from the [main download page](http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america.html) for North America, under "other formats"

Comment: I found it, thank you very much for your help! Maybe you know what the difference between changes in this update folder and URL (--server https://planet.openstreetmap.org/replication/minute) which I see when I run command "./utils/update.php --import-osmosis-all"?

Comment: OSM provides updates for the entire planet every minute, while [GeoFabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/technical.html) provides updates per region every day.

Comment: "OSM provides updates for the entire planet every minute,..." I hope a nominatim downloads only difference for currently installed maps ;)

Comment: I highly doubt about that....it opens lots of issues on the edge of the maps. I suggest you check for out-of-the-expected-extent entries in your database in a few minutes